# check if an option is selected before displaying the alert modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

i have a modal displayed  via JavaScript by clicking the button delete ( deleting an option from a select tag ) . i have to check if an option is selected before displaying the alert modal but i couldn't find a way to hide the alert modal even if nothing is selected

i used a JavaScript function to check but still after checking the alert modal appear

this is the html code :

```
<button  class="btn btn-danger" onclick="check()"  id="idButtonDelete" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-sm">delete</button>

<div id="idAlertModal" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
<div class="modal-content">
  ...
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is the code for the onClick check() function

```
function check(){

   if($("#select").val()==null){  //select id of the select tag 
    $(".bs-example-modal-sm" ).hide();

    alert("you should select an option first")


        return false;
                               }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution , i had to remove the attribute data-target=".bs-example-modal-sm" from the button and add it in the check() function if an option is selected

```
function check(){

if($("#select").val()==null){  //select id of the select tag 


alert("you should select an option first")


    return false;

   }else{
    $('#idButtonDelete').attr('data-target', '#idAlertModal');

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your default `option` of your `select` look like this:

```
<option value="">Default Option</option>
```

then you can use:

```
if($('#select').val() === '')
```

instead of:

```
if($("#select").val()==null)
```

---

You can try to use:

```
$('.modal').modal('hide');
```

instead of:

```
$(".bs-example-modal-sm" ).hide();
```

Comment: i used this one the problem persists , when i click on delete the alert("you should select an option first") is displayed ( it means if($("#select").val()==null) works fine ) but after that it display the alert modal also i want to hide this one

Comment: thank you , i tried it but the problem persists ( the second alert is still displayed )

Comment: right now i can't , but i can explain : i have i select with some options under this select i have a delete button when i don't select an option and i click on the delete button the alert("you should select an option first") is displayed then the alert of the modal is displayed which means  $(".bs-example-modal-sm" ).hide(); doesn't work on it

Comment: Maybe the problem in data-toggle="modal" attribute? Which tells to show/hide modal by button click.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.modal').modal('hide')
```

Comment: if($("#select").val()==null) works fine  and the alert("you should select an option first") is displayed but after this alert the alert modal is displayed ! it doesn't hide it

Comment: So the problem is in $(".bs-example-modal-sm" ).hide(); line?

Comment: yes apparently it doesn't work on modal or something

Comment: Maybe you are using some additional plug-in for modal and it is conflicting with your code. Please provide more info is this case.

Comment: yes i am using files bootstrap.js and bootstrap.min.js

Comment: i tried it , it still displays the modal alert i am thinking of deleting the data-target attribute from the button and add it in the else of the if if($("#select").val()==null)

Comment: Maybe the problem in data-toggle="modal" attribute? Which tells to show/hide modal by button click.

Answer (score 0):

```
function verifyAreaSelected(){

   if($("#select option:selected" ).val()==''){  //select id of the select tag 
    $(".bs-example-modal-sm" ).hide();
    alert("you should select an option first");
        return false;
             }


}
```